# how to create/implement an algorithm that mirrors a binary tree

Tags: tree, binary, elixir, addition

I'm new to Elixir, and trying to implement an insert/add function to mirror an existing binary tree. Appreciate all ideas.

Don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to implement a binary tree in Elixir, and that you are also familiar with binary trees. For that, you would need to use a struct (which is just a map behind the scenes).

```
defmodule TreeNode do
  defstruct value: nil, left: nil, right: nil 

  def new(value), do: %TreeNode{value: value}

  def insert(root = %TreeNode{value: rootValue}, value) when value < rootValue do
    %{root | left: insert(root.left, value)}
  end

  def insert(root = %TreeNode{value: rootValue}, value) when value >= rootValue do
    %{root | right: insert(root.right, value)}
  end

  def insert(nil, value) do
    %TreeNode{value: value}
  end
end
```

There's no lookup method, which is left as an exercise to you. Usage is pretty simple. Here we create a new tree node which will be the root:

```
iex(1)> node = TreeNode.new(10)
%TreeNode{left: nil, right: nil, value: 10}
```

Now we insert 5 into the tree:

```
iex(2)> node = TreeNode.insert(node, 5)
%TreeNode{
  left: %TreeNode{left: nil, right: nil, value: 5},
  right: nil,
  value: 10
}
```

And 12:

```
iex(3)> node = TreeNode.insert(node, 12)
%TreeNode{
  left: %TreeNode{left: nil, right: nil, value: 5},
  right: %TreeNode{left: nil, right: nil, value: 12},
  value: 10
}
```

And 11:

```
iex(4)> node = TreeNode.insert(node, 11)
%TreeNode{
  left: %TreeNode{left: nil, right: nil, value: 5},
  right: %TreeNode{
    left: %TreeNode{left: nil, right: nil, value: 11},
    right: nil,
    value: 12
  },
  value: 10
}
```

With the final shape of the tree resembling the following:

```
   10
 /    \
5     12
     /
    11
```

Mirroring now becomes pretty easy. Here's the module that implements the mirroring functionality:

```
defmodule TreeMirror do
  def mirror(nil), do: nil

  def mirror(node) do
    %TreeNode{value: node.value, left: mirror(node.right), right: mirror(node.left)}
  end
end
```

To mirror the node we have created earlier above, we simply call `TreeMirror.mirror`:

```
iex(5)> mirrored = TreeMirror.mirror node
%TreeNode{
  left: %TreeNode{
    left: nil,
    right: %TreeNode{left: nil, right: nil, value: 11},
    value: 12
  },
  right: %TreeNode{left: nil, right: nil, value: 5},
  value: 10
}
```

Now the shape of `mirrored` resembles the following:

```
   10
 /    \
12     5
  \
  11
```

Comment: Appreciate your great work, very well explained thank you. but I have a question:
 Can you please explain to me, how and when this function is called? 

def insert(nil, value) do
    %TreeNode{value: value}
  end

Comment: @RazakJ It's there in the code examples where I insert 5, 12 and 11 into the tree.

Comment: I tried to make a "Max heap". I've tried to swap right nodes to have the root as max value, but the code adds nodes only on the left side when the value is less than the root, and adds nodes only on the right side if its greater than the root, and swaps them. How to balance it?

part of code:
def insert(newValue=%MaxHeap{value: rootValue}, nextValue) do
if nextValue <= rootValue do
  %MaxHeap{newValue | left: insert(newValue.left, nextValue)}
else
  temp=rootValue
  rootValue=nextValue
  nextValue=temp
  %MaxHeap{newValue | right: insert(newValue.right, nextValue), value: rootValue}