# Function that takes a binary tree and returns the sum

Tags: tree, binary, sum, elixir

I'm new in to elixir and i have question that i'm stack in

a binary tree

Implement a function, `sum/1`, that takes a binary tree and returns the sum of all values in the tree. The tree is represented as follows:

```
 @type tree :: {:node, integer(), tree(), tree()} | nil
```

Comment: Too broad and looks like a homework. Also show where exactly have you stuck.

Comment: Sure looks like homework but who would be doing homework in _Elixir_?  I mean I love Elixir but it hardly seems the kind of language a prof would assign homework in.  Regardless vote to close--not only does it look like homework it looks like the questioner made no effort whatever to solve it himself.

Comment: survey of languages class. In college I took one and it had 8 different languages and one of them was a FP language. It's not unreasonable to think that in a modern version of the class a prof uses Elixir for that FP language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
@type tree :: {:node, integer(), tree(), tree()} | nil

def sum(nil), do: 0

def sum({:node, int, l, r}) do

  int + sum(l) + sum(r)

end
```

Comment: how dose this code work . Because I don’t see any line describes how we go recursively to the left node respective to the right node and sums them up , please clarify .

Comment: Your first int is the root node. You add to it sum(l) -(here is the recursive step)- which sums the left subtree. If the left subtree is nil, the first definition of sum applies and it just returns 0. If it is a node, the second def of sum applies until it reaches nil. It does the same thing when it sums the right subtree. I hope this was clear enough.

Comment: You can open Elixir and test it, if you haven't already. It usually helps for understanding. For test, you can use sum({:node, 5, {:node, 3, nil, nil}, {:node, 6, nil,nil}}). It represents a tree with 5 as a root and 3 and 6 as left and right nodes.

Comment: Thank you . What if the question said mirror the binary tree , what will you use to mirror it ?

Comment: bro you have my exam questions. You should make an effort to implement them so you can learn. I'm also quite new to elixir.

Comment: def mirror(nil), do: nil       
def mirror({:node,int,l,r}) do   
  {:node,int,mirror(r),mirror(l)}  
end

Comment: I solved it by creating a TreeNode with struct value left right, and then implented Mirror , Like this following

  def mirror(nil), do: nil

  def mirror(node) do
    %TreeNode{value: node.value, left: mirror(node.right), right: mirror(node.left)}
  end

Comment: Can you solve this problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54724056/how-to-create-implement-an-algorithm-that-mirrors-a-binary-tree

Comment: Maybe the add/2 function on page 9 is something similar to what you are looking for   https://people.kth.se/~johanmon/courses/id1019/exam/exam-2018-03-13-english-answers.pdf

Answer (score 1):

An example of a depth-wise tree walk in elixir that takes a function to be executed on each node is at https://gist.github.com/kipcole9/43f9551e3c579a7d33e8daed10359c2c

Basically separate the problem into two parts:

1. Walk the tree recursively
2. Apply a given function to act on the current node's value, the result of executing the function on the left branch and the result of executing the function on the right branch

   ```
   defmodule Treewalk do
     @type tree :: {:node, integer(), tree(), tree()} | nil

     def depth({:node, value, nil, nil}, _fun) do
       value
     end

     def depth({:node, value, nil, right}, fun) do
       fun.(value, depth(right, fun), nil)
     end

     def depth({:node, value, left, nil}, fun) do
       fun.(value, depth(left, fun), nil)
     end

     def depth({:node, value, left, right}, fun) do
       fun.(value, depth(left, fun), depth(right, fun))
     end

     # The function to be run on each
     # node of the tree which is passed
     # the current value, the result of
     # running the funciton on the left
     # branch and the result of running
     # the function on the right branch
     def adder(a, b, nil) do
       a + b
     end

     def adder(a, b, c) do
       a + b + c
     end

     # Test tess
     def tree do
       {:node,
         1,
         {:node, 2,
           {:node, 4, nil, nil},
           nil
         },
         {:node, 3,
           nil,
           {:node, 4, nil, nil}
         }
       }
     end

     def sum(tree) do
       depth(tree, &adder/3)
     end

     # run a test, returns 14
     def test do
       depth(tree(), &adder/3)
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: Sum/1 , This mean it takes one argument , but you implemented your adder with three argument, why ? I'm confused.

Comment: Edited to add the simply wrapper the honours the original question in detail.